# fastest way to insert from table to table

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

i generally use below query for inserting.
but this time i will use this query for 15 million records.
it's very slow this way.
how can i make it fast.

Only Id(Guid), Code(nvarchar) and pool(guid) values will be transferred. Rest is default as you can see.

Thanks.

```
insert into collection
select Id,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',Code,pool,1 from collectiontemp
where pool='0929B522-AF2A-4B36-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: . . Is this one query inserting 15 million records?  Or are you calling the query multiple times?

Comment: it's one query. there are 15 mil rows "select * from collection where pool='0929B522-AF2A-4B36-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'"

Answer (score 0):

This query is fine:

```
insert into collection
    select Id, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
           Code, pool, 1
    from collectiontemp
    where pool = '0929B522-AF2A-4B36-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

There is no obvious way to speed it up, other than having an index on `collectiontemp(pool)`.

However, if you are *calling* this query 15 million times with different values for `pool`, then that is expensive!  To load the entire table, remove the `where` clause:

```
insert into collection
    select Id, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
           Code, pool, 1
    from collectiontemp;
```

If you have a handful of values, list them in one query using `IN`:

```
insert into collection
    select Id, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
           Code, pool, 1
    from collectiontemp
    where pool in ( . . . );
```

Comment: can i make it inside loop? would it make it faster?

Comment: inside temp table there are other pools aswell, so i can't remove where clause, i guess. i only want that spesific pool to transfered.